# Python: How do you use lxml to parse xml tags with periods?

Tags: python, jenkins, lxml

I am attempting to parse Jenkin's job XML files using the lxml module for Python. It looks like this:

```
<triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
       <spec>H H(6-21)/3 * * *</spec>
</hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
```

I like using lxml's handy objectify module, but it gets confused when I try to do this:

```
root.triggers.hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.spec = 'something'
```

I get an `AttributeError: no such child: hudson`. Of course there's no attribute named hudson! How does one work with a goofy piece of XML like this?

For additional context, here is my code:

```
from lxml import objectify
import jenkins

j = jenkins.Jenkins('http://local.jenkins.instance')
xml = j.get_job_config('job_name')
root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
root.triggers.hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.spec = 'something'
```

Comment: Just a guess, but you might need to use `etree` instead.

Comment: That's too bad as I really like how clean objectify makes things. I did notice I could do `root.triggers.getchildren()[0].spec = period`, but that seemed like a hack.

Comment: If it works, then use it. I find using XPath to be just as straightforward as objectify, and it works with complex tags containing periods and colons, but to each his own.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if there was a way to do it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense that `triggers.hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger` interpreted as trying to access `<TimerTrigger>` element in the following structure, hence it complained about `hudson` child element not found when given OP's actual XML :

```
<triggers> 
  <hudson> 
    <triggers> 
      <TimerTrigger> 
        <spec>H H(6-21)/3 * * *</spec> 
      </TimerTrigger> 
    </triggers> 
  </hudson> 
</triggers>
```

One possible way to acess child element where name contains dots without having to switch to `etree` would be using `__getattr__()` method :

```
>>> root.triggers.__getattr__('hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger').spec
'H H(6-21)/3 * * *'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code using `lxml`'s [`etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) module worked for me to get the text from `<spec>`:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse("37757193.xml").getroot()
spec = root.xpath("//triggers/hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger/spec")[0]
print(spec.text)
```

returns `'H H(6-21)/3 * * *'`.